# KO3 ORM Questions

Tags: orm, kohana-3, kohana-orm

Kohana3 ORM newbie here.

I got few fast questions:

1. I got a following code `$user = ORM::factory('user')->where('key', '=', $key)->find();`. IT's working correctly however... How to check if the query return anything?
2. When I'm trying to update, new record is being instered. Why? `$user->status = '1'; $user->save();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use $user->loaded(). Please review [Unofficial Kohana 3.0 Wiki](http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php) for more resources and tutorials.
2. Is this your whole code?